# c#- Can't delete multi rows in datagridview with sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, checkbox, datagridview, delete-row

I've a datagridview in which i add some columns to it , The first column has checkbox 
when i try to select multirows with checkbox and delete it , it only deletes one row each time even when i select multi rows .

The code i use for filling the datagridview

```
 SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * From Data", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = "false";
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["id"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["car_num"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["customer"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["driver"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["first"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["second"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["sum"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["price"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["date1"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["date2"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["city"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["type"].ToString();

        }
```

The code i use for deleting

```
private void bDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

                if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete these data ? ", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    con.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Delete From Data Where id='"+item.Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * From Data", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

                da.Fill(dt);
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: does it raise en exception or just nothing happens?

Comment: Does the message box pop up multiple times if you have selected multiple rows and click delete?

Comment: Also where do you refill `dataGridView1` after clearing it in the delete method?

Comment: no , it doesn't raise an exception and the message pop up once

Comment: i refill the datatable dt

Comment: with the advice of @MisterMystery i removed dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); and now the message pop up multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` inside the foreach loop. Since the foreach loop iterates over `(DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)` then after the rows are cleared there is nothing left to iterate over.

Comment: i removed dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); and now the message pop up multiple times , Can't i do it once ?

Comment: You would have to move the if statement with the message box outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: Also dont refill the datatable from the database until the foreach loop is complete. You want to delete all the selected rows and then refill the datatable.

Comment: i removed the messagebox completley and did the refill after the loop but still the same.

Comment: i removed the refill and this fixed the problem , but how can i do the refill right ?

Comment: When do you do the refill? In your refill loop you set all the check boxes to false so it could be that you are deleting one row and then refilling which resets all the check boxes and not deleting any more.

Comment: Fixed it , i didn't set the refill after the loop correctly.