# Can't delete row from dataGridView in SQlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, delete-row

Could anyone please explain me, why the deletion does not work?

First problem: The row is visually deleted in the dataGridView, before I confirm the delete

Second problem: The entry will not be delete in the database. After reloading the program all is back again.

Third problem: If I delete a new row after "deleting" the first, no new Message Box appears.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete these data? ", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Version=3;"); //Create the connection with database
            dbConnection.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Delete From druckerliste Where id='" + item.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'", dbConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbConnection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
    }    
}
```

I use a little bit help of this question here: [c#- Can't delete multi rows in datagridview with sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796694/c-cant-delete-multi-rows-in-datagridview-with-sqlite-database)

There is a line called

```
if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
```

If I insert this, it gives me an exception, so I edit it with

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32("0")))
```

as I could find in this answer here: [Convert.ToBoolean fails with "0" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205436/convert-toboolean-fails-with-0-value)

But with that line not even the Message Box appears the first time and no success Message.
So now, I dont know what's wrong.

**Edit:**

I've found a partial solution.
I edit the line

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Delete From druckerliste Where id='" + item.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", dbConnection);
```

(item.Cells[0] instead of item.Cells[1])

but the problem is, that always the first entry of the dataGridView will be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution and yes, it was really silly what I did before.

First fault was to use the RowsRemoved-Event instead of KeyDown-Event.

Second fault was to not change the SelectionMode to FullRowSelect

After that, I use the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Datensatz löschen?", "Frage", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                int rowID = int.Parse(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
                SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Version=3;");
                dbConnection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM printerlist WHERE id='" + rowID + "'", dbConnection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```